# How to create script which activates virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv, sh

I'd like to have a script which activates particular virtualenv.

I did this:

file: *go.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
source environments/admin2/bin/activate
```

but after execution it virtualenv is **not** activated.

Perhaps it dies after script execution. I need the script that could do activation in current bash/zsh, because now I'm forced to this ugly routine.

After signing in to ssh session do:

```
cat go.sh
```

and then copy paste the result O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing go.sh this way:

```
source go.sh
```